# Evaluate the definite integral -inf to inf (x^2 - 7x + 1)/(x^4 +1) dx

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^2 - 7x + 1}{x^4+1} \mathrm{d}x$$

I am having a lot of trouble starting this one. I believe it wants me to use the residue theorem. I started off by equating $x^4+1$ to $z^4+1 = 0$ and trying to find the roots. I came up with $(z-i\sqrt{i}), (z+i\sqrt{i}), (z-\sqrt{i}), (z+\sqrt{i})$. This entire assignment deals with $(x^4 +1)$ in the denominator and I don't know if its correct. From there, I don't know what I am suppose to do with the numerator in terms of evaluating the integral from there. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Alternately, you could just simply use the fact that $x^4+1=(x^2-x\sqrt2+1)(x^2+x\sqrt2+1)$.

Comment: In fact, $\quad\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^{2n}+1}dx=\frac\pi n\bigg(b\cdot\csc\frac\pi{2n}+\csc\frac{3\pi}{2n}\bigg).~$ As it can be seen, the coefficient of *x* does not influence the outcome of the integral at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate the fraction along a path that contains a segment of the real axis, encloses a big portion of the upper half plane, and never touches the lower half plane, you get $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues at the poles in the upper half plane.

On the other hand, as you expand the path homothetically,the integral alon the portion of the path not contained in the real line tends to zero (this is because the degree of the denominator is at least $2$ larger than the one of the numerator).

Therefore the integral you seek is $2\pi i$ times the residues of the poles of the fraction in the upper half plane.

These residues are $\frac{x^2-7x+1}{4x^3}$ evaluated on the poles in the upper half plane.

These poles are $e^{\pi i/4}$ and $e^{3\pi i/4}$.

Comment: Did I get the right answers for the poles? I'm not sure exactly how to do the steps for this

Comment: @user134982 Yes, but you need to determine which of them are in the upper half plane. I assume that you are denoting $\sqrt{i}$ for $e^{\pi i/4}$. Then $\sqrt{i}$ and $i\sqrt{i}$ are the ones in the upper half plane.